# Git big code rewrite common practice

Tags: git

I am fairly new to git. I have been using it for a website project for the last two months having one copy to my work computer one to my home computer and one on bitbucket.

I usually work on my local machine for small changes and push them to bitbucket with no issues.

My website consists of php and other static assets. Last week I decided it was time to rewrite the js architecture which means I'm going to mess with html php stuff too.

I know I can create another branch to work with my new release but what about the daily small changes that conflict with that branch?

I only read about new features and fast deployments but not about big releases and conflict problems.

What are the best practices for these situations?

Comment: I can advice you to read about [git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow). It helps you to work structured with git and your changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your branch as up-to-date as possible with your small changes.  Having to deal with conflicts isn't a bad thing.  It is when the conflicts get large and unwieldy that problems happen.

Make sure that you merge your small changes into the refactor branch.  That way anything that you haven't refactored gets updated and any conflicts that happen can be resolved with the change fresh in your mind.  By keeping the branch up to date with master will make merging it back in easier and fairly painless.  Otherwise you would be dealing with one big conflict that will be difficult to resolve correctly and easily.

Comment: 'Having to deal with conflicts isn't a bad thing' this is the sentence everyone should begin with when talking about git! Really!